# iOS 11 navbar smooth scrolling

Tags: uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, ios11

Have been trying to use standard components to maintain smoothness of iOS system components. Smoothness of scrolling specifically, as this is one of the items central to the user experience while being fairly subliminal.

Nav bar scrolling has been stuttering, and really cannot find out why, please see video below:

https://vimeo.com/user37760602/review/231886597/248f03ae84

Note that ScoreBreak app, in blue, has a non-smooth scroll, yet first party Apple Notes app has a very smooth scroll here. Currently at a loss for what we can do differently with our table views and nav bars.

Thank you for taking a look and hope you have a great day,
Jordan from Denver